# Use one Formula in multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want to use a formula in multiple sheets.
for example:

I have a sheet named "Formulas" and in cell "A1", There is a text "B1+B2"
Now, I want to run this formula in Sheet1 and Sheet2.
So, If I Edit "Formulas!A1" to "B1+B2+B3", in all sheets, results change.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the formulas of different sheets, like Sheet1 and Sheet2 when a formula is edited in a third sheet, like Formulas, then you should use Google Apps Script including an on edit trigger.

The above because Google Sheets doesn't include a built-in feature that does that. An alternative to write the script by yourself is to use and add-on. You could look for existing add-ons in the G Suite Marketplace

References

- [Use add-ons & Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) function.

The result will be exactly what you expect:

> So, If I Edit "Formulas!A1" to "B1+B2+B3", in all sheets, results change

*Note: In order to make the function work you will be asked to "link" the sheets. Just go ahead and accept it.*

Comment: IMPORTRANGE imports only the result of a formula not the formulas.